# how to get Multiple collection cell in one collection View without creating XIB

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have one collection view in which i have to add multiple cell with different UI without Creating XIB

how can i create it

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you facing?

Comment: @Sarthak could you post code so that people can help

Comment: i have not done any coding part yet

In this question User have to select start time from the 1st date picker...now user will select end time from the 2nd date picker...suppose user have selected 08:00 AM then end time will no more then 08:30 AM...if he select 08:31 AM or more than we have to show alert

Comment: Please try to code and then ask a query if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: Uploded the coding part that i have done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the property `maximumDate` of `UIDatePicker`.
Whenever user changes the startDatePicker, set the maximumDate of endDatePicker to 30 mins more than the start.
You can do this in the target for valueChanged action of startDatePicker.

```
startDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startDatePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

Your `startDatePickerValueChanged` function can be

```
@objc func startDatePickerValueChanged() {
    let newStartDate = startDatePicker.date
    endDatePicker.maximumDate = newStartDate.add(component: .minute, value: 30)!
}
```

Comment: you should set minimum date as well `endDatePicker.minimumDate = newStartDate`

Comment: @pawan in wich VC i have to write above code

Comment: @Sarthak did you change the entire question? The question I answered was originally about UIDatePickers.